# jquery mobile hide the main content after submit a form with ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, mobile

When I submit the form with ajax everything seems to work but the content is hidden. I can only see it on the "inspect element" but not in the browser.

Any suggestion?

this is the code that i'm using. I already try with .triger(create)

```
$("#submit").click(function(){

            var formData = $("#post").serialize();

            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: "ajax.php",
                cache: false,
                data: formData,
                success: function (data) {
                       $('#allfeeds').append().html(data);
                       $("#content ul").listview('refresh');                           

                    }
             });               
            });
```

Thank you in advance for your help.

Update. Thank you for your help. I used the append() method and it is working!

Comment: use  `$('#allfeeds').html(data);` instead of  `$('#allfeeds').append().html(data)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use either `append()` or `html()` to insert the data but you are using both in wrong way

```
 $('#allfeeds').html(data);
```

Or

```
 $('#allfeeds').append(data);
```

Comment: And if it's the same data, you would end up having multiple copies of the same data - duplcates. Hence, be sure to use $('#allfeeds').empty().html(data) or $('#allfeeds').empty().append(data)